# Pandas still getting SettingWithCopyWarning even after using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

At first, I tried writing some code that looked like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)
train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan, 1, 2], size=(10, 3)), 
                     columns=['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch'])

complete = train.dropna()    
complete['AgeGt15'] = complete['Age'] > 15
```

After getting SettingWithCopyWarning, I tried using.loc:

```
complete.loc[:, 'AgeGt15'] = complete['Age'] > 15
complete.loc[:, 'WithFamily'] = complete['SibSp'] + complete['Parch'] > 0
```

However, I still get the same warning. What gives?

Comment: This is the best article I've read on this topic:  https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/  
It is also addressed in the Pandas docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=chain#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note: As of pandas version 0.24, `is_copy` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. While the private attribute `_is_copy` exists, the underscore indicates this attribute is not part of the public API and therefore should not be depended upon. Therefore, going forward, it seems the only proper way to silence `SettingWithCopyWarning` will be to do so globally:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

---

When `complete = train.dropna()` is executed, `dropna` might return a copy, so
out of an abundance of caution, Pandas sets `complete.is_copy` to a Truthy
value:

```
In [220]: complete.is_copy
Out[220]: <weakref at 0x7f7f0b295b38; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7f7eee6fe668>
```

This allows Pandas to warn you later, when `complete['AgeGt15'] = complete['Age'] > 15` is executed that you may be modifying a copy which will have no effect on `train`. For beginners this may be a useful warning. In your case, it appears you have no intention of modifying `train` indirectly by modifying `complete`. Therefore the warning is just a meaningless annoyance in your case.

You can silence the warning by setting,

```
complete.is_copy = False       # deprecated as of version 0.24
```

This is quicker than making an actual copy, and nips the `SettingWithCopyWarning` in the bud (at the point [where `_check_setitem_copy` is called](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L1559)):

```
def _check_setitem_copy(self, stacklevel=4, t='setting', force=False):
    if force or self.is_copy:
        ...
```

---

If you are really confident you know what you are doing, you can shut off the `SettingWithCopyWarning` globally with

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None # None|'warn'|'raise'
```

---

An alternative way to silence the warning is to make a new copy:

```
complete = complete.copy()
```

However, you may not want to do this if the DataFrame is large, since copying 
can take a significant amount of time and memory, and it is
completely pointless (except for the sake of silencing a *warning*) if you know `complete` is already a copy.

Comment: Do you think this is consistent? It raises the same warning with `drop_duplicates` but not with `drop`.

Comment: @ayhan: There is also no warning if `complete = complete.assign(AgeGt15=(complete['Age'] > 15))` is used. The mechanism Pandas uses to infer `SettingWithCopyWarning` is not fool-proof. It catches the most common cases, but not all.

Answer (score 3):

I resolve it by creating copy of dataframe:

```
complete = train.copy()
```

Comment: Although the marked answer recommends using is_copy, it is not the best way to handle as is_copy will also throw  an error message saying it is deprecated -- [see panda docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html). In light of this, copy() is the best way to ensure no warning messages are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `.loc` solution would work, if it wasn't for the `np.nan`s in the original data frame. You could either `complete = train.dropna().reset_index()` or [Pandas .assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) will avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning` and is the recommended way of creating new columns, returning a new data frame object. Your example:

```
complete = complete.assign(**{'AgeGt15': np.where(complete['Age'] > 15, True, False)})
```