# How to properly add a new column using pandas based on two existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am totally new to Python (and pandas). I really tried to solve this problem, however, I couldn't solve it without getting the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I have two columns containing the *first name* and *last name* of a person. What I'm looking for is a way to add a new column to my data frame *df* containing the *full name*. This following code worked with warning:

```
df['Full Name'] = df['First Name'] + " " + df['Last Name']
```

Next, I tried

```
df.loc[:,'Full Name'] = df.loc[:,['First Name']] + " " + df.loc[:,['Last Name']],
```

which is invalid.

Comment: What is code above `df['Full Name'] = df['First Name'] + " " + df['Last Name']` ?

Comment: because `df['Full Name'] = df['First Name'] + " " + df['Last Name']` is nice and obviously works perfect.

Comment: @ jezrael. Thank you for your comments! Exactly, but I am still getting warnings, which is not nice in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: How is your `df` defined?

Comment: I read a csv file into a data frame using the following command: df= pd.read_csv('...')

Comment: @PatrickBalada - what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: pandas: 0.19.1 (and python: 3.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably want to do

```
df.loc[:,'Full Name'] = df.loc[:,'First Name'].astype(str) + " " + df.loc[:,'Last Name'].astype(str)
```

or

```
df.loc[:,'Full Name'] = df.loc['First Name'].astype(str) + " " + df.loc['Last Name'].astype(str)
```

(.astype(str) may be too much in ur case)

then, you will probably still receive the warning for the reasons you can see in the message (check out this answer [Pandas still getting SettingWithCopyWarning even after using .loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809796/pandas-still-getting-settingwithcopywarning-even-after-using-loc/38810015#38810015))

A short answer here is to write

```
 df.is_copy=False
 df.loc[:,'Full Name'] = df.loc[:,'First Name'].astype(str) + " " + df.loc[:,'Last Name'].astype(str)
```