# How to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas?

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I want to convert the type of a column to int using pandas. Here's the source code:

```
# CustomerID is missing on several rows. Drop these rows and encode customer IDs as Integers.
cleaned_data = retail_data.loc[pd.isnull(retail_data.CustomerID) == False]
cleaned_data['CustomerID'] = cleaned_data.CustomerID.astype(int)
```

This raises the warning below:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame

How can I avoid this warning? Is there a better way to convert the type of CustomerID to int? I'm on python 3.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38809796/190597

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it in one `loc`:

```
retail_data.loc[~retail_data.CustomerID.isnull(),'CustomerID'] = retail_data.loc[~retail_data.CustomerID.isnull(),'CustomerID'].astype(int)
```

---

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

retail_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,1)*10, columns=['CustomerID'])
retail_data.iloc[2,0] = np.nan
print(retail_data)

   CustomerID
0    9.872067
1    5.645863
2         NaN
3    9.008643

retail_data.loc[~retail_data.CustomerID.isnull(),'CustomerID'] = retail_data.loc[~retail_data.CustomerID.isnull(),'CustomerID'].astype(int)

       CustomerID
0         9.0
1         5.0
2         NaN
3         9.0
```

---

You'll notice that the dtype of the column is still float, because the `np.nan` cannot be encoded in an `int` column.

If you really want to drop these rows without changing the underlying retail_data, make an actual `copy()`:

```
cleaned_data = retail_data.loc[~retail_data.CustomerID.isnull()].copy()
```