# pandas: operations using groupby yield SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'team': ['Warriors', 'Warriors', 'Warriors', 'Rockets', 'Rockets'],
    'player': ['Stephen Curry', 'Klay Thompson', 'Kevin Durant', 'Chris Paul', 'James Harden']})
```

When I try to group on the `team` column and perform an operation I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
for team, team_df in df.groupby(by='team'):
    # team_df = team_df.copy()  # produces no warning
    team_df['rank'] = 10  # produces warning
    team_df.loc[:, 'rank'] = 10  # produces warning

SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
df_team['rank'] = 10
```

If I uncomment the line generating a copy of the sub-DataFrame, I don't get the error. Is this generally best practice to avoid this warning or am I doing something wrong?

Note I don't want to edit the original DataFrame `df`. Also I know this example can be done a better way but my use case is much more complex and requires grouping an original DataFrame and performing a series of operations based on a different DataFrame and the specs of that unique group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you grok [this article](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) and are
confident you know how to avoid chained indexing (through use of `.loc` or
`iloc`) then you can turn off the `SettingWithCopyWarning` with
`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` and never be bothered by this warning ever again.

Since you wrote

> Note I don't want to edit the original DataFrame df

and you are properly using `.loc` to assign to `team_df`, it is clear you
already know that modifying the copy (`team_df`) will not modify the original
(`df`), so the `SettingWithCopyWarning` emitted here is just a nuisance.

The `SettingWithCopyWarning` comes up in all sorts of situations where you are
coding properly, even with `.loc` or `.iloc`. There is no "proper" way to code
which avoids sometimes triggering `SettingWithCopyWarning`s.

Therefore, I would just turn off this warning globally with

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

---

I would generally not recommend using `team_df = team_df.copy()` just to avoid
`SettingWithCopyWarning`s -- copying a dataframe can be a drain on
performance especially when the dataframe is large or if done many times in a loop.

If you want to [turn off the warning in just one
location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810015/190597), you could use

```
team_df.is_copy = False
```

It serves the same purpose but will not be a performance drain.  Note, however,
that `is_copy` is not mentioned in the official Pandas API, so it may not be
guaranteed to exist or be useful for this purpose in all future versions of
Pandas. So if robustness is a priority but performance isn't then maybe use
`team_df = team_df.copy()`. But I think the sounder way for an experienced
Pandas programmer to go is to either turn the warning off globally or -- if you
want to be very careful -- keep the warnings, check them manually, but accept
that it will sometimes be triggered by correct code.

Comment: @piRSquared: I learned of [the article](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) from [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411802/alexander), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809796/pandas-still-getting-settingwithcopywarning-even-after-using-loc/38810015#comment76884959_38809796).

Comment: As you guessed, `is_copy` is already deprecated in Pandas v0.24.2, but there is now `_is_copy`.

Answer (score 0):

The [pandas split apply combine docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) aren't great on this. This should point you in the right direction

```
def apply_fun(team_df):
    team_df['rank'] = 10
    return team_df

df.groupby('team').apply(apply_fun)
df['column_rank'] = df.groupby('team')['column'].transform(lambda x: x.rank())
```