# SettingWithCopyWarning when implementing column comparison

Tags: python, pandas

i am using the answer from [Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)
in my script but it returned me 'SettingWithCopyWarning', may i know how should i fix it?

attemped1: dff['changed'] = dff.col1.ne(dff.col1.shift(1))
attemped2: dff.loc[:, 'changed] = dff.col1.ne(dff.col1.shift(1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, problem is in some line above.

I guess you filter your `DataFrame` and solution is add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
dff = df[df['col2'] == 1].copy()
dff['changed'] = dff.col1.ne(dff.col1.shift(1))
```

If you modify values in `dff` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: is it true that without copy() will modify original dataframe? i don't see the effect in the test case below?
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col2':[111,222,333], 'col3':['aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa']})
dff = df[df.col3 == 'aaa']
dff.loc[0, 'col3'] = 'zzz'

Comment: @user466130 - Give me a sec.

Comment: @user466130 - No, there is no modification in original df. It is warning, because possible [chaining indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983664/2901002) for explanation with sample data.

Comment: @user466130 - Also there are another way for turn off this warning, [`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45110013/2901002)