# Misleading SettingWithCopyWarning when assigning on result of DataFrame.dropna?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Under certain cases, doing an assignment on a DataFrame created using `.dropna()` emits the infamous `SettingWithCopyWarning`. So I followed what [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61240274/554319) suggests, and inspected the `._is_view` and `._is_copy` attributes:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, np.nan, 2, np.nan], 
   ...:                    [2.0, 3.0, 5, np.nan], 
   ...:                    [np.nan, 4.0, 6, np.nan]], columns=list("ABCD")); df1                                                                                                                                                              
Out[3]: 
     A    B  C   D
0  1.0  NaN  2 NaN
1  2.0  3.0  5 NaN
2  NaN  4.0  6 NaN

In [4]: df2 = df1.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")   

In [5]: df2._is_view, df2._is_copy                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: (False, <weakref at 0x7f56e8ecfd60; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7f56e916f9d0>)

In [6]: df2["A"] = df2["A"].fillna(df2["B"])                                                                                                                                                                                                  
<ipython-input-6-9c99ac454f90>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df2["A"] = df2["A"].fillna(df2["B"])
```

However, this `_is_copy` is set to None if you actually call `.copy()` (misleading variable name?), which on the other hand removes the warning:

```
In [17]: df3 = df1.dropna(axis="columns", how="all").copy()                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [18]: df3._is_view, df3._is_copy                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[18]: (False, None)

In [19]: df3["A"] = df3["A"].fillna(df3["B"])                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [20]:
```

But, finally, `.fillna` result does have `_is_copy` set to `None`:

```
In [20]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, np.nan], [2.0, 3.0]], columns=["A", "B"]); df1                                                                                                                                                             
Out[20]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  3.0

In [21]: df2 = df1.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [22]: df2._is_view, df2._is_copy                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[22]: (False, None)

In [23]: df2["A"] = df2["A"].fillna(df2["B"])                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [24]:
```

Can anybody explain what's the meaning of the `SettingWithCopyWarning` in this context and why do I still get despite `_is_view` being `False` in all cases?

I am particularly worried about this, in light of what the pandas docs say:

> Sometimes a `SettingWithCopy` warning will arise at times when there’s no obvious chained indexing going on. **These** are the bugs that `SettingWithCopy` is designed to catch!

Comment: xref https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39448

Answer (score 0):

The SettingWithCopyWarning is raised because there is potential ambiguity in value assignment. When you assigned values to `df2["A"]`, and pandas knows that `df2` is derived from `df1`, it is not clear if the change should also affect `df1`, which is why the warning is raised so that the user can check. pandas tracks this using `_is_copy`, so `_is_view` doesn't really have anything to do with it. If you manually create an explicit copy with `copy()`, pandas knows the user does not expect changes in `df2` to affect `df1`, and thus does not raise warnings.

As for your observation that `dropna` is not consistent in setting `_is_copy`, it has to do with how the dataframes were created, and how `dropna` was implemented.

The following is the first `df1`:

```py
# First df1
In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
   ...:     ...:     [2.0, 3.0, 5, np.nan],
   ...:     ...:     [np.nan, 4.0, 6, np.nan]], columns=list("ABCD"))

In [4]: df1
Out[4]:
     A    B  C   D
0  1.0  NaN  2 NaN
1  2.0  3.0  5 NaN
2  NaN  4.0  6 NaN

In [5]: a = df1.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")

In [6]: a._is_copy
Out[6]: <weakref at 0x7f94e78427c0; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7f94d5ad06d0>

In [7]: a
Out[7]:
     A    B  C
0  1.0  NaN  2
1  2.0  3.0  5
2  NaN  4.0  6
```

Notice that one column is dropped.

Following is the second `df1`:

```py
# Second df1
In [8]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, np.nan], [2.0, 3.0]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [9]: df1
Out[9]:
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  3.0

In [10]: b = df1.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")

In [11]: b
Out[11]:
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  3.0

In [12]: b._is_copy # No output, i.e. is None
```

Notice that none of the columns were all NaNs, thus no columns were dropped.

Following is an excerpt of the source code for `fillna`:

```py
# permalink: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/951239398789b077689371d30906cab5b9248f4e/pandas/core/frame.py#L6014
...

    if np.all(mask):
        result = self.copy()
    else:
        result = self.loc(axis=axis)[mask]

...
```

Apparently, if no rows met the criteria to be dropped, a copy of the dataframe is returned. Else, an indexed dataframe using `.loc` is returned.

Comment: The conversation in the GitHub issue suggests that this behavior is not intended though

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to see that with `df2 = df1.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")`

1. If something is dropped, `df2._is_copy_` is referencing to the `df1`, warning happens if you try to modify `df2` in some way
2. If nothing drops, `df2._is_copy_` is `none`, no warning

This difference must have been done under the hood of `dropna()`

See the comment in the post: [pandas-still-getting-settingwithcopywarning-even-after-using-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810015/8071529)