# How to change multiple Pandas DF columns to categorical without a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, categorization

I have a DataFrame where I want to change several columns from type 'object' to 'category'.

I can change several columns at the same time for float,

```
dftest[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']] = \
    dftest[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']].astype(float)
```

For 'category' I can not do it the same, I need to do one by one (or in a loop like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28910914/427129)).

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2']:
    dftest[col] = dftest[col].astype('category')
```

Question: Is there any way of doing the change for all wanted columns at once like in the 'float' example?

If I try to do several columns at the same time I have:

```
dftest[['col1','col2']] = dftest[['col1','col2']].astype('category')
## NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time
```

My current working test code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

factors= np.array([
        ['a', 'xx'],
        ['a', 'xx'],
        ['ab', 'xx'],
        ['ab', 'xx'],
        ['ab', 'yy'],
        ['cc', 'yy'],
        ['cc', 'zz'],
        ['d', 'zz'],
        ['d', 'zz'],
        ['g', 'zz'] 
        ])

values = np.random.randn(10,4).round(2)

dftest = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([factors,values]), 
                  columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])

#dftest[['col1','col2']] = dftest[['col1','col2']].astype('category')
## NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time

## it works with individual astype
#dftest['col2'] = dftest['col2'].astype('category')
#dftest['col1'] = dftest['col1'].astype('category')

print(dftest)

## doing a loop
for col in ['col1', 'col2']:
    dftest[col] = dftest[col].astype('category')


dftest[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']] = \
    dftest[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']].astype(float)

dftest.dtypes
```

---

output:

```
col1    category
col2    category
col3     float64
col4     float64
col5     float64
col6     float64
dtype: object
```

== [update] ==

I don't have a problem using the loop now that I know the trick, but I asked the question because I wanted to learn/understand WHY I need to do a loop for 'category' and not for float, if there is no other way of doing it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the point? Speed?

Comment: @IanS see my update

Comment: "Not implemented" generally means it is planned for a future version. Categoricals are relatively new so we may expect `.astype('category)` to work for more than 1 column in the future.

Comment: FYI: `DataFrame.astype('category')` is implemented and available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not immediately clear what the result of `dftest[['col1','col2']].astype('category')` should be, i.e. whether the resulting columns should share the same categories or not.

Looping over columns make each column have a separate set of categories. (I believe this is a desired result in your example.)

On the other hand, `.astype(float)` works differently: it ravels the underlying values to a 1d array, casts it to floats, and then reshape it back to the original shape. This way it may be faster than just iterating over columns. You can emulate this behaviour for `category` with higher level functions:

```
result = dftest[['col1', 'col2']].stack().astype('category').unstack()
```

But then you get a single set of categories shared by the both columns:

```
result['col1']
Out[36]: 
0     a
1     a
2    ab
3    ab
4    ab
5    cc
6    cc
7     d
8     d
9     g
Name: col1, dtype: category
Categories (8, object): [a < ab < cc < d < g < xx < yy < zz]
```

Comment: Thanks @ptrj, I see now that the problem is not the casting to another type but how to handle the levels in the case of categorical columns. I did not think on that, but make perfect sense to me now. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
In [99]: pd.concat([dftest[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category')), dftest.ix[:, 'col3':].astype('float')], axis=1)
Out[99]:
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0    a   xx  0.30  2.28  0.84  0.31
1    a   xx -0.13  2.04  2.62  0.49
2   ab   xx -0.34 -0.32 -1.87  1.49
3   ab   xx -1.18 -0.57 -0.57  0.87
4   ab   yy  0.66  0.65  0.96  0.07
5   cc   yy  0.88  2.43  0.76  1.93
6   cc   zz  1.81 -1.40 -2.29 -0.13
7    d   zz -0.05  0.60 -0.78 -0.28
8    d   zz -0.36  0.98  0.23 -0.17
9    g   zz -1.31 -0.84  0.02  0.47

In [100]: pd.concat([dftest[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category')), dftest.ix[:, 'col3':].astype('float')], axis=1).dtypes
Out[100]:
col1    category
col2    category
col3     float64
col4     float64
col5     float64
col6     float64
dtype: object
```

but it won't be **much** faster, as `apply()` method uses looping under the hood

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, but the aim of the question was more about "why I can not change type to category for several columns like in float?". I wanted to know if it was a limitation of my pandas knlowledge. See update